# Pytorch cifar10 images are not normalized

Tags: pytorch

```
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
  
trainset.data[0]
```

I am using the above code and expect that data will be normalized. But it is not, below is the result. I need to access data using the data method to do some more processing. Output is below.

```
array([[[ 59,  62,  63],
        [ 43,  46,  45],
        [ 50,  48,  43],
        ...,
        [158, 132, 108],
        [152, 125, 102],
        [148, 124, 103]],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `torchvision.transforms.Normalize` is merely a *shift-scale* operator. Given parameters `mean` (the `"shift"`) and `std` (the `"scale"`), it will map the input to `(input - shift) / scale`.

Since you are using `mean=0.5` and `std=0.5` on all three channels, the results with be `(input - 0.5) / 0.5` which is only normalizing your data if its statistic is in fact `mean=0.5` and `std=0.5` which is of course not the case.

With that in mind, what you should be doing is providing the actual dataset's statistics. For CIFAR10, these can be for example found [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fb.resnet.torch/issues/180):

```
mean = [0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465]
std = [0.2470, 0.2435, 0.2616]
```

With those values, you will be able to normalize your data properly to `mean=0` and `std=1`.

*I've written a more general, long-form answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874807/how-to-do-normalization-in-cnn/68876047#68876047).*

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html , i am follow this. What i am seeing is that when I use the below code , i can see values are normalized.

dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
print(images.shape , images[0])

tensor([[[0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843,  ..., 0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843],
         [0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843,  ..., 0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843],
         [0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843,  ..., 0.9843, 0.9843, 0.9843],
My doubt is when I use trainset.data[0] , I do not see normalized value but when I load and then get the value it is working

Comment: The transform pipeline (including the `T.Normalize` transform) is applied by the dataloader (in your example the train dataloader to be more precise, not the test dataloader), **not the dataset**. This the reason why `trainset.data[0]` is not normalized.